# Cron job scheduled to run on specific day-of-week is running on last day of month as well

Tags: cron

I have a cron job scheduled to run every Thursday at 6am via the following schedule:

```
0 6 * * 4
```

It's been running as expected, but on Tues, September 30th it ran (unexpectedly) and again on Thursday, October 2nd (as expected). Are there any "gotchas" with running jobs using the  day-of-week schedule that I should be aware of? Is this just an anomoly due to something else unknown on my end?

Comment: Did you check if are present in `/etc/cron.monthly` scripts that do extra run of your job?

Comment: I'm unable to check that file at my host (Pantheon), but I've opened a ticket with them to see if something else is possible. Thus far they say nay.